# Multiple `gsub` in multiple `each` loops getting overriden one by another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

Trying to iterate over some phrases, and whenever I find a word, I need to replace it with a link.

```
phrases = ["hello world", "worldwide"]
words_to_link = ["world", "world"]
```

I am trying to get:

```
"hello <a href='world'>world</a><br />worldwide"
```

My code is:

```
phrases.each do |ph|
  words_to_link.each do |w|
    ph.gsub!(w, "<a href='#{w}'>#{w}</a>")
  end
end.join("<br />").html_safe
```

The output of this is:

`"hello <a href='<a href='world'>world</a>'><a href='world'>world</a></a><br /><a href='<a href='world'>world</a>'><a href='world'>world</a></a>wide"`

On the first run it finds all occurrences of `world`, but on the second, it goes inside the generated `<a href="#world">world</a>` and `gsub`s again.

Another problem is the proper regex to only find words by boundaries, I thought it would be `/\b(word)\b`, but that didn't work.

Any pointers?

Comment: It seems like in this example you could change the `words_to_link` array to have only one element. Currently it has the same word twice.

Comment: Yes, this is a simplified example, but the array can have repetitions

Comment: It seems like this wouldn't work if the array had repetitions.

Comment: Is there an alternate way to approach this multiple substituiton @maxpleaner ?

Comment: Try out regular expressions on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com). I think the posted answer is a good approach. Not sure about the word boundaries problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, so may have got the wrong end of the stick here. However, here is an answer by my interpretation:

```
phrases = ["hello world", "worldwide"] 
substitutions = { /\bworld\b/ => "world" } 

phrases.each do |ph| 
  substitutions.each do |pattern, replacement| 
    ph.gsub!(pattern, "<a href='#{replacement}'>#{replacement}</a>") 
  end 
end

phrases.join("<br />").html_safe
```

You can use `\b` in a regex to mark a work boundary, to avoid altering the `"worldwide"` string. And (I *think* this is what you wanted?) you can define some *mapping* between the search/replace terms rather than looping though twice, to avoid the double-replacement.

Comment: Thank you for the regex bit, I will reflect on the code you posted to flip mine more around it.